# Split string into multiple alpha and numeric segments

Tags: c#

I have a string like "ABCD232ERE44RR". How can I split it into separate segments by letters/numbers. I need:
Segment1: ABCD
Segment2: 232
Segment3: ERE
Segment4: 44

There could be any number of segments. I am thinking go Regex but don't understand how to write it properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;   
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var substrings = Regex.Split("ABCD232ERE44RR", @"[^A-Z0-9]+|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[0-9])|(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Z])");
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",substrings));
    }
}

Output : ABCD,232,ERE,44,RR
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest thinking of this as finding matches to a target pattern rather than splitting into the parts you want. Splitting gives significance to the delimiters whereas matching gives significance to the tokens.

You can use [Regex.Matches](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9712a7w(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Searches the specified input string for all occurrences of a specified regular expression.

```
var matches = Regex.Matches("ABCD232ERE44RR", "[A-Z]+|[0-9]+");

foreach (Match match in matches) {
     Console.WriteLine("Found '{0}' at position {1}", match.Value, match.Index);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
((A-Z)+(\d)*)+
```

Answer (score 0):

If you decide not to use regex, you can always go the manual route.

```
const string str = "ABCD232ERE44RR1SGGSG3333GSDGSDG";

var result = new List<StringBuilder> 
{
    new StringBuilder()
};

char last = str[0];

result.Last().Append(last);

bool isLastNum = Char.IsNumber(last);

for (int i = 1; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    char ch = str[i];

    if (!((Char.IsDigit(ch) && isLastNum) || (Char.IsLetter(ch) && !isLastNum)))
    {
        result.Add(new StringBuilder());
    }

    result.Last().Append(ch);
    last = ch;
    isLastNum = Char.IsDigit(ch);
}
```